# How to write junit test for exceptions which are explicitly thrown

Tags: java, mockito, junit5

I have a method that takes in the String, and check if it contains another string. If it does, then it throws a custom exception.

```
Class Test{
    String s2="test";
    public void testex(String s1){
        if(s1.contains(s2))
            throw new customException();
    }
}
```

I am trying to write a unit test for this:

```
@Test (expected = customException.class){
 when(s1.contains(s2)
                .thenThrow(new customException());
}
```

However, my test is failing with the error as-- java.lang.Exception: `Unexpected exception, expected customException but was<org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException>`

Comment: Why are you mocking what you want to test? I can't make sense of the example. Also, types in Java are always in `PascalCase` -> `CustomException`.

Comment: Moreover, the question is tagged junit5 but the @Test annotation seems to be from Junit 4. This adds to my confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This test doesn't seem to be particularly useful, but I believe your issue is that Mockito's when() expects a method call for a mocked object.

```
@Test(expcted = CustomException.class)
public void testExMethod() {
    @Mock
    private Test test;
    when(test.testEx()).thenThrow(CustomException.class);
    test.testEx("test string");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite following your example test. It looks like you're mocking your actual class with Mockito rather than writing a junit test. I would write a test like this:

With junit's assertThrows method:

```
@Test
void stringContainingThrowsError() {
    Test myClassThatImTesting = new Test();
    assertThrows(CustonException.class, () -> myClassThatImTesting.testex("test"))
}
```

With a normal assertion:

```
@Test
void stringContainingThrowsError() {
    Test myClassThatImTesting = new Test();
    try {
        myClassThatImTesting.testex("test");
        fail();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        assertTrue(ex instanceof CustomException);
    }
}
```